# Android service to watch if app is running

Tags: android, service, sticky, application-restart

I'm creating a survey app for our offices, and I want this app always running and in foreground, but for some reasons (usually by user) this app is sent in background or killed, so I need to create a service that watches if my app is running and in foreground, if not it re-launches it again, I'm really confused with sticky service in the app it self or a broadcast receiver or even an independent service that watches all activities and relaunches mine if not present in the list

any advice please ?

Thanks,

Comment: Posting as a comment as my suggestion is not directly answering your question. What you need is to create your survey app as a launcher so that you can remain in foreground as long as you want.

Comment: Rajesh, yes it did, but it's deployed in separate offices and a wrong use or crash can happen at any time, so I want to ensure that my app will restart without moving to the office, and more the devices are protected in enclosures so the employees there can't access them, you see :)

Comment: It sounds to me like what you want is for your app to impose a kind of "kiosk mode". Something like [this](http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/) may be a good start. Having a service run and try to re-launch your app sounds very hacky and I don't think it will work very well.

Comment: Exactly Dave, kiosk mode is the main keyword, I've no problems with buttons they are phisically hidden by an enclosure, and for now I'm able to restart the app if killed by a sticky service, but not bringing it to foreground when sent in background accidently by pressing home button (only in dev)